# SQL Select the similar products

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have the following DB structure: (MySQL)

```
product(id,name)
category(id,name)
category_manager(id,fk_product,fk_category)
```

I want to select the similar products when I have a product. Selection should be done based on each product's categories. I want probably something like WP similar posts, but I don't know how to write it down.

Let me give you an example.
E.g.

I have 3 products with the following:

```
product(id,name)
product(1,towel)
product(2,coat)
product(3,tshirt)
product(4,shoes)
....

category(id,name)
category(1,wool)
category(2,cotton)
category(3,windproof)
category(3,synthetic)
category(4,lether)
....

category_manager(id,fk_product,fk_category)
category_manager(1,1,1)
category_manager(2,1,2)
category_manager(3,2,2)
category_manager(4,2,3)
category_manager(5,3,1)
category_manager(6,4,4)
....
```

If I have the towel's id how can I select the following products :

"`3,tshirt`" (because it is in category "`1,wool`")

"`2,coat`" (because it is in category "`2,cotton`")

??????

It's probably a join statement but...

Comment: I would rename the category_manager table product_category, and remove the surrogate key as it appears to serve no purpose. Also, I don't understand in what sense you have 3 products. And yes, it's probably a join

Comment: @Strawberry your sentence doesn't make sence. I dont have product_manager. I have a category_manager and category table. The category table has all the categories. and the category_manager has the relations for the products and the categories.

Comment: The category and product table table should be complete different tables, because IF a category should deleted or renamed, it should be from the category table. In that way, you dont affect the relations

Comment: @Strawberry I think that was a typo; he has 3 *tables*, not 3 *products*.

Comment: ok, product gets you to category (categories) via 3rd table let's call a Junction which gets you back to product in another alias to product for those categories to get all other products

Comment: so join em up and you are all set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need self join manager table:

```
select p.* 
from manager m1
join manager m2 on m1.fk_category = m2.fk_category
Join product p on m2.fk_product = p.id
where m1.fk_product = 1 and m2.fk_product <> m1.fk_product
```

Comment: I am trying to add some extra join on your code but it returns me #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'p'

Comment: `select distinct p.*
from manager m1,foo  f1

join manager m2 on m1.fk_category = m2.fk_category
join foo f2 on f1.fk_anotherID = f2.fk_anotherID

Join product p on m2.fk_product = p.id
Join Products p on f2.fk_product = p.id

where m1.fk_product = 1 and m2.fk_product <> m1.fk_product
    and
      f1.fk_anotherID = 2 and f2.fk_product <> f1.fk_product`

Comment: table foo is foo(id,fk_product,fk_anotherID)

So, I want to do another one join to the previous results, but now based not in the product Id but in the foo.anotherID .

Is it possible in a single sql statement?

Comment: You have join `product p` twice. Change to `join product p1` and `join product p2`

Comment: So, it has to be like that??

Comment: `select distinct p1.*
from manager m1,foo  f1, product p1

join manager m2 on m1.fk_category = m2.fk_category
join foo f2 on f1.fk_anotherID = f2.fk_anotherID

Join product p1 on m2.fk_product = p1.id
Join Product p2 on f2.fk_product = p2.id

where m1.fk_product = 1 and m2.fk_product <> m1.fk_product
    and
      f1.fk_anotherID = 2 and f2.fk_product <> f1.fk_product`

Comment: Something like that. Dont use old syntax join like `select distinct p1.* from manager m1,foo f1, product p1`

Comment: and what syntax I should folllow ? :S now I confused.

Comment: Instead of `select * from table1, table2` you should write as `select * from table1 join table2 on table1.col = table2.col`

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong and I understood you properly

```
SELECT p.name, c.name 
FROM product p
JOIN category_manager cm on p.id = cm.fk_product
JOIN category c on cm.fk_category = c.id
```